# Javascript function only allowing for one class on an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a navigation item to a site built by someone else. They wrote a javascript function that is only allowing one class to be on an anchor tag. I need to add a second class to the last navigation item that will give it a border-right. The .last class is already written in CSS and I have put .last on the proper anchor tag, but because of the javascript it will only render .active in the browser and not the .last class. Any ideas on how to do that with this function or with the html I already have? Thanks.

Javascript function:

```
function setActive() {
  aObj = document.getElementById('navigation').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(i=0;i<aObj.length;i++) { 
  if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0) {
     aObj[i].className='active';
  }
 }
}

window.onload = setActive;
```

CSS:

```
#navigation .MainNavigation li a.last{
border-right:#648558 2px solid;
}

#navigation .MainNavigation li a.active{
padding:12px 19px 12px 17px;
background: url(/_images/bkgd_Active.png) repeat;
}
```

URL of page: http://securitybank.designangler.com/insurance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
aObj[i].className='active anotherclassname';
```

Or add to existing classes with:

```
aObj[i].className=aObj[i].className + ' active';
```

Comment: The second one is what I wanted since I only wanted to add this class on one item. Thank you for your help. =)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if it's the last item, only with CSS:

```
#navigation .MainNavigation li:last-child a {
   border-right:#648558 2px solid;
}
```

Comment: Not what I was looking for but still a useful way to do it.